# Is there a standart way to sync off-chain metadata (assets, tokens, mints) like cardano-db-sync does with on-chain data (epochs, blocks etc)?

Tags: cardano-node, cardano-db-sync, syncing, asset

I have running **cardano-node-ogmios:v5.6.0_1.35.5** in couple with **cardano-db-sync:13.1.0.0** ([docker-compose.yml](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-graphql/blob/master/docker-compose.yml)) and looking for the solution to sync off-chain assets localy. Is there any standart solution for that?

I've noticed that some assets (27200 items) have been copied localy to postgres database by service **cardano-graphql-background:8.0.0** but have no idea why only 27200 assets and either I can copy more assets using this service?

I would greatly appreciate any help.

[image: Asset schema created by cardano-graphql-background]